# NoMethodError when using stub in a helper class in RSpec 3 - but not RSpec 2?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, unit-testing, rspec, rspec-rails, rspec3

I have a number of helper classes stored under my `spec/support` directory which i reuse in a number of tests. For example, `foo_helper.rb`

```
class FooHelper
  def self.stub_thing
    Foo.any_instance.stub(:thing)
    Foo.any_instance.stub(:thing=)
  end
end
```

`Foo` is used in a number of tests, so i would just `require ../spec/support/foo_helper.rb` in each spec i wanted to be able to use `FooHelper.stub_thing`. This all worked fine in RSpec 2.x

Having upgraded to RSpec 3.1, I'm seeing the following depreciation warning:

```
Using `any_instance` from rspec-mocks' old `:should` syntax without explicitly enabling the syntax is deprecated. Use the new `:expect` syntax or explicitly enable `:should` instead. Called from app/spec/support/foo_helper.rb:4:in `stub_thing'.
```

So, having added `rspec-actvemodel-mocks` to my Gemfile:

```
gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 3.1'
group :development, :test do
  gem 'rspec-activemodel-mocks', '~> 1.0'
end
```

And following [the documentation](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/docs/working-with-legacy-code/any-instance), i changed my code to:

```
class FooHelper
  def self.stub_thing
    allow_any_instance_of(Foo).to receive(:thing)
    allow_any_instance_of(Foo).to receive(:thing=)
  end
end
```

Which, then causes my tests to fail with the following error:

```
 Failure/Error: FooHelper.stub_thing
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `allow_any_instance_of' for FooHelper:Class
 # ./spec/support/foo_helper.rb:4:in `stub_amount'
 # ./spec/models/parent_model.rb:33:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

How can `allow_any_instance_of` not be defined, when `any_instance` and `stub` are?!

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this as well after updating RSpec in one of our apps. For anyone else running into it, and who hasn't explicitly selected the `should` syntax, just add `extend RSpec::Mocks::ExampleMethods` to the beginning of the class or module in which you're trying to use these methods.

Answer (score 0):

`allow_any_instance_of` is only enabled when the `expect` syntax is enabled, per http://www.rubydoc.info/github/rspec/rspec-mocks/RSpec/Mocks/ExampleMethods:allow_any_instance_of. Presumably, you configured RSpec to work only with the older `should` syntax.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but no i haven't explicitly configured it to use the `should` syntax - i don't think!) I am using the vanilla `spec_helper.rb` and `rails_helper.rb` generated by running `rails generate rspec:install`...

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this issue as well. Are you by any chance calling it from a `before :all` block? Apparently this isn't allowed, because it worked after moving it to a `before :each`.

Hope that helps!